# Method Not Allowed :403 Forbidden Flask ,Next AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, stripe-payments, amazon-route53, amazon-lightsail

I'm getting error "method not allowed" in my /stripe_hook method when I try to make a rest api call to my function.I'm using AWS Amplify, Route53, Lightsail with Stripe payment gateway. Other API calls are working absoultely fune but not /stripe_hook.I have configured this as live webhook on stripe On checking the header logs it says below

```
> POST /stripe_hook HTTP/2
> user-agent: insomnia/2023.4.0
> accept: */*
> content-length: 0

* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):

< HTTP/2 405 
< content-type: application/xml
< allow: HEAD, DELETE, GET, PUT
< server: AmazonS3
< x-cache: Error from cloudfront
< via: 1.1 42d3cbd98a.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< x-amz-cf-pop: SIN52-C3
< x-amz-cf-id: zHwy2ypNs_ecck0tDbwLIFdMTKjiVqbmdUvw==
```

authentication.py

```
from __main__ import app

from time import time
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify

from utils.user_utils import get_user_by_username
from utils.user_utils import get_normalized_username

from utils.user_utils import add_user
from utils.user_utils import approve_user


from utils.helper_utils import get_error_reponse


import stripe

@app.route('/api/auth/login', methods=['POST'])
def login_local():
    data = request.get_json()    
    username = get_normalized_username(data['email'])
    secure_password = get_secure_password(data['password'])
    user = get_user_by_username(username)

    if not user or user['password'] != secure_password or 'is_active' not in user or user['is_active'] != True:
        return get_error_reponse(422, 'The email address or password you entered is incorrect or the account does not exist')
    
    return jsonify(user)


@app.route('/api/auth/signup', methods=['POST'])
def signup_local():
    data = request.get_json()

    email = get_normalized_username(data['email'])
    add_user(
        email=email,
        password=get_secure_password(data['password']),
        given_name=data['given_name'],
        family_name=data['family_name'],
    )
    user = get_user_by_username(email)
    return jsonify({'message': 'Success'})



stripe.api_key = "sk_test_XXX"

endpoint_secret = 'whsec_XXX'


@app.route('/stripe_hook', methods=['POST'])
def verfiy_user_payment():
    
    event = None
    payload = request.data
    sig_header = request.headers['STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
            payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret
        )
    except ValueError as e:
        raise e
    except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
        raise e
    if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed':
        print("checkout event")
        customer_email = event['data']['object']['customer_details']["email"]
        session2 = event['data']['object']
        client_reference_id = session2.get('client_reference_id')
        user = get_user_by_username(customer_email)
        approve_user(user['id'])
    if event['type'] == 'payment_intent.succeeded':
      payment_intent = event['data']['object']
      print("verified")
    # ... handle other event types
    else:
      print('Unhandled event type {}'.format(event['type']))

    return jsonify(success=True)
```

Is there anything I'm missing or is there something wrong?

I tried to make it as OPTIONS method but still not able to call the API. I also simply tried to create a POST method and just returned with 200 but it also failed.

Comment: It seems like the Cloudfront configuration is off. It says `< allow: HEAD, DELETE, GET, PUT`, meaning you will need to add POST/OPTIONS to your config for it to work. Also, just to clarify, you will never have to call this webhook endpoint yourself, a request will be sent to it by Stripe.

Comment: @vanya Where do I need to update it? I'm not using any Cloudfront distribution. In distribution it is empty

Comment: @vanya Also if you see I have other API calls that is working absolutely fine with POST method.

Comment: From your error log, you stripe endpoints try to access your S3 bucket, but `POST` method is not alowed from your S3 config.

Comment: Clearly your request has been routed to S3 and not to your authentication.py function (`< server: AmazonS3`).
I see that the other API endpoints are behind `/api`and the one failing is behind `/stripe_hook`. Do you have a behaviour associated with `/api*` routing to your function and a default behaviour routing to S3?

Comment: @MarcC  Nothing is related to /api. I tried with /api also but it didn't work. I know it's not related to auth.py file and is related to some issue with Route53/Cloudfront/S3 but don't know here it is failing as all the other are working

Comment: My suggestion was that it was a routing issue with your CloudFront distribution. What are the behaviours associated with your distribution?  

Your request hit the CloudFront distribution (`< via: 1.1 42d3cbd98a.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)`) then got routed to S3 (`< server: AmazonS3`).

Comment: @MarcC but my CloudFront distribution is empty

Comment: Then that’s an issue. You have at a minimum a default behaviour associated with ‘*’ and one origin.

Comment: @MarcC Other endpoints are working fine without the Cloud Front also. I also found this might be the issue so I tried creating a cloud front distribution with all the API methods and also updated (tried both cases updating in Route53 and not updating in Route53) but still it's the same error.

Comment: Is it working when you skip the CloudFront definition (I mean calls to `https://myapi/stripe_hook`)?

Comment: @MarcC No, it's not working then also :(

Comment: great progress, so it has nothing to do with CloudFront. 
how do you deploy your service?  
your question does not include details on this aspect.